# EF code first return subset of columns

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework-4, code-first

I have a table with about 12 columns.  But there are time when I only need 2 or 3 columns.

I am using Entity Framework code first to query the database from my website.

What should I do so that I do not query all the columns but only a subset of columns?

Thanks,
Mike

Answer (score 3):

You can use a projection to an anonymous type that contains the properties you want, i.e if your `Foo` entity has the properties A, B and C you could do:

```
var results = context.Foos.Select( x => new { x.A, x.B });
```

to retrieve only the properties A and B.